# How to correct " 'coroutine' object has no attribute 'data'" Error when using Telethon for Telegram?

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram, telethon

I am trying to code a simple thing in Python to automatically download some media from a Channel on Telegram. I am using Telethon for this.

I keep getting an error that I cannot solve and for which I do not understand the reason.

"'coroutine' object has no attribute 'data'"

I have tried to use asyncio as well, but it didn't work.
Here below my latest code

```
# In[1]:

import asyncio
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
import telethon.sync
from telethon import TelegramClient
from telethon.sync import TelegramClient

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()


# In[2]: 

api_id = #MyAPIID
api_hash = 'TheHash'
phone_number = '+34xxxxx'
channel_username = 'meanwhileinromania'


# In[3]: 

client = TelegramClient('session1', api_id, api_hash)

client.start()




# In[4]:DOWNLOAD


msgs = client.get_messages(channel_username, limit=100)
for msg in msgs.data:
    if msg.media is not None:
        client.download_media(message=msg)
```

I get for [3]:

```
<coroutine object AuthMethods._start at 0x00000190D413F9C8>
```

and at [4]:

```
    C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\ipykernel_launcher.py:3: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'MessageMethods.get_messages' was never awaited
  This is separate from the ipykernel package so we can avoid doing imports until
RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
 in 
      2 
      3 msgs = client.get_messages(channel_username, limit=100)
----> 4 for msg in msgs.data:
      5     if msg.media is not None:
      6         client.download_media(message=msg)

AttributeError: 'coroutine' object has no attribute 'data'
```

Answer (score 32):

If `msgs` is a co-routine, it needs to be awaited. So likely the line before the loops should be `msgs = await client.get_messages(channel_username, limit=100)`