# how to get messages of the public channels from Telegram

Tags: python, telegram, telethon

I need to read the messages of some public channels in the telegram application,
I want to store telegram channle text in a text file. I want use python. I try with telethon but it's so complicated. my code have some error:

```
from telethon.tl.functions.messages import (GetHistoryRequest)
from telethon.tl.types import (
PeerChannel
)
client = TelegramClient(username, api_id, api_hash)
client.start()

offset_id = 0
limit = 100
all_messages = []
total_messages = 0
total_count_limit = 0

while True:
    print("Current Offset ID is:", offset_id, "; Total Messages:", total_messages)
    history = client(GetHistoryRequest(
        peer="https://t.me/futballbadnews",
        offset_id=offset_id,
        offset_date=None,
        add_offset=0,
        limit=limit,
        max_id=0,
        min_id=0,
        hash=0
    ))
    if not history.messages:
        break
    messages = history.messages
    for message in messages:
        all_messages.append(message.to_dict())
    offset_id = messages[len(messages) - 1].id
    total_messages = len(all_messages)
    if total_count_limit != 0 and total_messages >= total_count_limit:
        break
```

error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-24-52082a022807> in <module>()
---> 24     if not history.messages:

AttributeError: 'coroutine' object has no attribute 'messages'
```

Comment: Maybe you need to use `await history`?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/50975793

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to correct " 'coroutine' object has no attribute 'data'" Error when using Telethon for Telegram?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57147419/how-to-correct-coroutine-object-has-no-attribute-data-error-when-using-te)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> How to get messages from a public channel on Telegram using Telethon?

Take a look into the [documentation](https://docs.telethon.dev/en/stable/modules/client.html#telethon.client.messages.MessageMethods.get_messages), so you can see how to set up correctly the `get_messages` request.

```
import asyncio
from telethon import TelegramClient
from telethon.tl import functions, types

client = TelegramClient('YOUR_SESSION_NAME', 'YOUR_API_ID', 'YOUR_API_HASH')
client.start()

async def main():
    channel = await client.get_entity('CHANNEL USERNAME')
    messages = await client.get_messages(channel, limit= None) #pass your own args

    #then if you want to get all the messages text
    for x in messages:
        print(x.text) #return message.text
   

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#then if you want to get all the messages text
for x in messages:
    print(x.text) #return message.text
```

TypeError: 'coroutine' object is not iterable

Comment: Should this answer the question somehow?

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34954892)