# How to get usenames of message senders from telegram chat

Tags: python, telegram, telethon

How to get usernames of message senders from telegram chats. Now I can get only user id from the code below

```
channel_entity=client.get_entity(group_title)
posts = client(GetHistoryRequest(
    peer=channel_entity,
    limit=limit_msg,
    offset_date=None,
    offset_id=0,
    max_id=0,
    min_id=0,
    add_offset=0,
    hash=0))

post_msg = posts.messages

# save the results
all_msg = []

for m in post_msg:
    print(m.from_id.user_id) #Here I get user id, but I need user name
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`GetHistoryRequest` is an old way of receiving such messages. I took [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60510841/5625547) as an example for the new style.

---

That said, you'll need to use `m.from_id` to get the complete use, in which the name will be available:

```py
for x in messages:
    participants = await client.get_participants(x.from_id)
    for p in participants:
        print(p.username, p.first_name)
```

This will show a list of usernames and first names of the sender

---

Full code I've used to get a list of user names of one of my groups:

```py
import asyncio
from telethon import TelegramClient
from telethon.tl import functions, types

client = TelegramClient('anon', '12345', '12345678901234567890')
client.start()

async def main():
    channel = await client.get_entity(-123456789)
    messages = await client.get_messages(channel, limit=100) 

    for x in messages:
        participants = await client.get_participants(x.from_id)
        for p in participants:
            print(p.username, p.first_name)

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(main())
```